# "unknown conversion type character 'l' in format" warning. Specifically when using MinGW Makefiles generated by cmake for Assimp

Tags: makefile, cmake, g++, mingw, assimp

I've been trying unsuccessfully for a week to get a build of Assimp that is linkable with a project I'm compiling with MinGW.

It seems that the makefiles that cmake generates to build Assimp 4.1.0 are flawed somehow because when I try to use them I get some warnings which ultimately lead to a failure when trying to link "libassimp.dll"

```
CMakeFiles\assimp.dir/objects.a(Exporter.cpp.obj):Exporter.cpp:(.text+0x1571): undefined reference to `Assimp::ExportScene3MF(char const*, Assimp::IOSystem*, aiScene const*, Assimp::ExportProperties const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
code\CMakeFiles\assimp.dir\build.make:3159: recipe for target 'code/libassimp.dll' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [code/libassimp.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:289: recipe for target 'code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [code/CMakeFiles/assimp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:131: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Before it gets to this the only error it seems is a format error in certain header files which use the %llu conversion type when referencing the ai_snprintf function.

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

I'm using the latest MinGW which has g++ version 6.3.0, by default using the c++14 standard. I did a test to see if this standard on windows didn't support %llu but when I wrote a CMakeLists.txt file, generated a makefile, and compiled using the makefile, it gave no errors and ran as expected.

I've tried using cmake to generate a Visual Studio 2017 project and building it there and it links fine when used in Visual Studio. If I call the same functions and compile with MinGW it doesn't link, I guess this is just an interoperability problem, but it suggests I have everything assimp needs to be built properly.

My thoughts are, somehow assimp's cmake modules are defining what standard assimp should be compiled with, and that standard doesn't support %llu, but that sounds silly. I don't like to assume something is a bug but these warnings don't seem like they're thrown because I forgot to do something.

I've tried editing the makefile it gives me and adding to the front:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 $(DEBUG)
```

Cause somewhere it said that could work, but it didn't change anything.
I also tried defining the macro __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1 for cmake but that didn't do anything either.

But I really don't know much about building binaries (though I've learned more than I expected to recently), so any advice, information, guidance is appreciated.